# How to lower battery consumption on a S6 edge

Tags: battery-life, google-apps, system-apps

Im not sure on what site I should be asking this. 
So my phone is an s6 edge and it consumes too much energy. Im curious of how we can reduce the phone consumption using some app or root option I can use. 
Thanks for your answers !

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of things you can do, but keep in mind that the mythical method of doubling your battery life doesn't exist. You may get another hour or two before you need to recharge.

1. Greenify (I am in no way affiliated)- An app that, like some other task killers, stops background tasks, but greenify is different. It uses the native force stop function to stop apps that you don't want to keep running. It runs better with root, but isn't necessary.
2. Turn off WiFi scanning- did they forget to mention wifi never turns off? Depending on your Android version, this option is either within the wifi advanced settings, or inside of the location services (marshmallow and on). You will find an option that says wifi scanning. Turn it off, along with wifi on while asleep if you are it. Wifi use is usually one of the larger drains of the battery.
3. Use your phone less. We are so hypnotized by there things, and it can't hurt to try and stay off Pokemon go on the bus when you could be watching the scenery or just listening to music.

Comment: One addition: Sometimes the Gapps (Google Apps) are more active than you would want. You can stop them by getting root and installing a custom ROM and/or remove the preinstalled Gapps and install the smallest possible Gapps package - pico - which is barely enough to keep the Play Store but reduces the resources used by the Gapps by a lot